# Effective way of constructing MySQL query in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am developing a portlet in which I access a database quite often. I have to specify the query in a way, that offers the possibility of filtering as a reaction on a user input. The parameters used for filtering are two at the moment, but this number can grow in the future.

At the moment, my construction works pretty well for all inputs, however, I dont think that I am doing it in a right/effective way, since I do not use prepared statement and just construct the query manually.

This is example of my code (**serviceFilter** is an arrayList and **typeFlag** is a String)

```
private String prepareQuery() {
        String query = "SELECT * from messages ";

        // check filters
        if (!typeFlag.equals("ALL")) {
            if (typeFlag.equals("XML")) {
                query += "WHERE type='" + TYPE_XML + "'";
            } else {
                query += "WHERE type='" + TYPE_JAVA + "'";
            }
        }

        // lets see if user specifies some service filtering
        if (serviceFilter.size() > 0) {
            if (!typeFlag.equals("ALL")) {
                query += " AND (";
            } else {
                query += " WHERE (";
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < serviceFilter.size(); i++) {
                if (i>0) {
                    query += " OR ";
                }
                String service = serviceFilter.get(i);
                System.out.println("Filter: " + service);
                query += "sender='" + service + "' OR receiver='" + service + "'";
            }
            query += ")";
        }

        query += " ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT " + String.valueOf(limit);

        System.out.println(query);

        return query;
    }
```

First problem is, that this has no way to prevent SQL injection (which would not be such a big problem since all the inputs come from checkBoxes and scrollbars, so the user does not actually type anything). I am not sure how to use a prepared statement here, because the population of my arrayList can be quite long and changes for every query.

The query itself, due to this fact can get really long. Here is an example of a query just for two arguments (imagine this for 20 items):

```
SELECT * from messages  WHERE (sender='GreenServiceESB#GreenListener' OR receiver='GreenServiceESB#GreenListener' OR sender='queue/DeadMessageQueue' OR receiver='queue/DeadMessageQueue') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50
```

So basically, my question is: Is this an effective way of constructing my query (propably not, right)? What approach would you suggest?

PS: I am using JDBC to connect to db and execute the query, if it is important in any way...

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: Carry on the construction of the sql that way only use parameters and prepared statements to execute the query.

Comment: Ok, it didnt occur to me that I can use the prepared statement dynamically (with the indexes from my for loop). So the construction like this (appending string for every additional condition) is ok?. I was hoping there would be some easier and "nice" way xD But you are probably right...

Comment: And one comment: Change datatype of query to StringBuilder and use append().

Comment: Thanks, StringBuilder is definetely a better option..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use something like

```
  create.selectFrom(BOOK)
  .where(PUBLISHED_IN.equal(2011))
  .orderBy(TITLE)
```

instead of

```
  SELECT * FROM BOOK
  WHERE PUBLISHED_IN = 2011
  ORDER BY TITLE
```

you can look to http://www.jooq.org/. It will simplify your code and you can avoid things like "if (something) { sql += " WHERE ..." }". This is antipattern and should not be used when possible.

Comment: This seems useful. But how would I use this when I do not know the number of arguments (.where and .and, .or in this case)? I will need to append these conditions during my loop for example...

Comment: something like

query = create.select...
while (I have contitions)
{
query = query.where(...)
}

Even if it may look the same, it is not. You actually are not concatenating strings in a loop (expensive operation; use StringBuilder at least) and this is safe - you don't have to handle the SQL syntax for different conditions. This really helps, mainly when you have to alter the larger SQL later, trust me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you hinted at one of your issues - not using a `PreparedStatement`.  Taking user input and using it directly in a SQL statement opens a site to SQL injection attacks.

I think what you're wanting is this:

```
select * from (
  select *, row_number over (order by id_desc) as rowNum
  from messages
  where sender in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) --8, 16 or however many ?'s you'll need
    or receiver in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
) results
where rowNum between (1 and ?)
order by rowNum
```

Now, you bind the parameters with whatever the user input is and if you have extra spots in you `IN` operator left over, you bind them with some value that can't (or likely won't) be in your table such as `null` or `HiMom#2$@`.  If you need to support an arbitrary number of values, you run the query multiple times and sort the results in memory yourself.

As far as the `row_number` function, that may not work in MySQL (I'm not a MySQL guy) but it does have an equivalent (or it could be that `limit` may be parameterizable, I don't know.